# Sheriff of Nottingham - Is the sheriff allowed to take your bribe and still search your bag?

Tags: sheriff-of-nottingham

I was playing in a game where I had offered a bribe on my merchant bag. The sheriff, in turn, chose to take my bribe and still search my bag anyway.  Is this type of play allowed?

Comment: I saw this in Hot Network Questions, thought it was Law Stack Exchange, and was rather puzzled.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No.**

The sheriff can *either* take the bribe *or* search the bag, not both. From [the rules](https://www.arcanewonders.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Sheriff_of_Nottingham_Rulebook.pdf), in Phase 4 (Inspection):

> When the Sheriff has made a decision about a Merchant Bag, he has two choices:
>
> - Accept whatever final bribe was offered (if any) and hand the bag back to its owner; or
> - Reject any bribe that may have been offered and unsnap the Merchant Bag, revealing the cards inside.

Comment: Thank you! Darn, when I was playing it, I didn't know this. Time to get my money back!

Answer (score 5):

No, once the bribe is taken is it a binding contract.

[Rules](https://gusandcodotnet.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/son_rulebook_ch09_singlepages.pdf)

> Once the Sheriff has made a choice it cannot be changed.
>   As soon as you unsnap a Merchant Bag or hand it back,
>   it’s too late to change your mind!
>
> After the Sheriff hears your offer (and after any negotiation
>   required to settle the issue), the Sheriff must either allow you
>   to pass (accepting any bribe that may have been
>   offered), and hand you your Merchant Bag,
>   or inspect the bag (refusing any bribe that
>   may have been offered).
>
> Normally, all deals you make must
>   be honored! However, there are a
>   couple of exceptions:
>   • Promises of future favors, which take place after the current
>   inspection phase, are not binding!
>   • A merchant might offer the sheriff a bribe, which includes
>   Goods in his merchant bag. Of course, he might be lying
>   about the contents of his bag. If he is allowed to pass, when
>   he reveals the Goods in his bag, he need only pay the sheriff
>   the Goods he promised which actually exist! If he promised
>   Goods to the sheriff, which are not in his bag, he does not
>   have to pay those.

As a side note in the group I played with bribes where frequently offered to open bags as well.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not allowed. Only promises of future action are non-binding. See the same question on [Boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1394636/are-bribes-binding).